# STL deque based tree vs own implementation of binary tree?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

This is a follow up to
[Is a list implementation of binary tree scalable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715389/is-a-list-implementation-of-binary-tree-scalable/10715698)

What can be the advantages or disadvantages of tree implementation done 
using linear array(stl vector) or stl deque

rather than a binary tree with individual nodes having left and right pointers?

assumptions:
the tree will be precomputed and will not be modified once built, and will only be used for searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'd say it's something of these:

- with a pointer-tree, you use memory for *data and pointers to data*, while with `std::vector` you only allocate memory for the *data* (the container deals with iterating through itself)
- if you use `std::vector`, you memory is localized. E.g. if you want to access a single full *level* of a tree, that will be sequential in memory, while with individual nodes allocated separately, you would jump through the memory like a bunny rabbit accessing all that
- if you allocate individual nodes, you actually have no way to allocate them except individually. That means a lot of calls to the `malloc`-euqivalent function. (There are some tricks you could use to avoid that in *C*, and they still work in `C++`, but why go with hacks if you have a ready `std::vector` solution).
- when creating a vector, you can use `std::vector.reserve()` to preallocate all the memory. Additionally, if you know how vector operates, you know that it will call a `malloc`-equivalent for reserving memory approximately every time you start a new level of your tree - number of allocations should be roughly equal to number of levels in your tree
- accessing elements of a vector is so easy, navigating through a vector-based fully populated binary tree is very intuitive and easy to work with

Answer (score 2):

Arrays (including `std::vector`) provide good [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and save some space, since they keep data in a contiguous block, whereas a pointer tree may scatter its nodes all over memory and incur allocator overhead.

For a precomputed tree, prefer storing it in a `vector`. A *complete* (or near complete) binary tree can be stored very efficiently using the layout commonly used for [binary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation).

(The overhead in a tree can be avoided by picking a good allocator, but the C++ standard library only offers a generic one.)